# Does a USB Isolator work any different than a powered single-port USB Hub?

Tags: usb

I was [looking at buying a USB Isolator](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/5201/501); however, I ended up buying [a powered four port USB 3.0 instead](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005HARR2W). It was roughly the same price, has a higher speed, and serves a useful alternative function.

Do these two devices work any differently. They're both powered externally? Will both of these be equally effective at eliminating a ground loop?

Answer (score 1):

A USB hub will probably tie all the grounds together, so that won't help you break your ground loop.

Update: I just checked a [Belkin F5U701 hub](http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F5U701) with my multimeter (in continuity mode). The grounds of all the USB ports are tied together and tied to the ground of the power supply.

Comment: Why would they do that if it takes an external power supply? Why not just use the ground from the transformer?

Comment: I can't help you with the why part - better to ask at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/, where people with experience designing USB hardware can answer. I updated my answer with some information about a hub that I have lying around.

Comment: @EvanCarroll It's much simpler. The actual data signal levels are relative to ground, so if they wanted to separate the grounds they'd have to convert the signals as well — all of which is extra complexity mostly unrelated to the digital-logic-type functions of a USB hub per se.

Comment: hrm... why are digital signals relative to ground? I thought that was a function of analog signals. I thought digital signals were on or off? Sorry if it's a stupid question, I don't work on such low levels though.

Comment: Digital signals are a special case of analog signals. Voltage is a potential difference, so you need something to reference your signal against.

Comment: @ObscureRobot We do design of electronics on EE, please do not send people whom have consumer electronics problems to us. I know this is something that we could answer, but I prefer it comes from a consumer perspective and this ground loop issue is very different from what someone designing a device like this worries about.

Comment: @EvanCarroll You are correct, 0 and 1 can be thought as on and off with a light switch, but in a transistor world you always must have a reference. [Relays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay) are more what you are talking about, but a [CMOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmos) instead uses a ground reference and either passes the voltage of your power rail or the power of your ground rail.

Comment: @Kortuk - the question here relates to the typical design of USB hubs. It is far more relevant to EE than AVP. I stand by my recommendation that this question be moved to EE, and will continue to make similar recommendations where appropriate.

Comment: @ObscureRobot But for such a migration to take place a moderator from EE will be checked with a moderator. If you flag and request a migration then you possibly get a migration, posting a comment multiple places gives a much higher chance of a double post. I can see this question relates more to EE then to AVP, but that does not mean it is a good fit for EE. It seems to have received an answer here and has not been closed.